# castle scheduler - cluster

Tags: castle-windsor, scheduled-tasks

We're using the castle scheduler component: http://using.castleproject.org/display/Comp/Castle.Components.Scheduler?showChildren=false

I have a wcf service which creates the tasks and that does it's job fine.

I then have a console app running (will be a windows service eventually) which should then keep an eye out for tasks to run.

Thing is the each create their own scheduler in the DB but they both have the same clusterid.

Should the console app be able to run the tasks created by the wcf service? If not - how can i make it do that?

Cheers

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are advised to not use the castle scheduler.

The guys are building a quartz integration and i have offered my help.